# Terminating a thread accessing a server

Tags: java, android, networking

There are several posts on Stackoverflow on how to to terminate a thread. The general consensus is to use a shared variable that acts as a flag that you set from outside the thread. You call the Interrupt method on the thread and the thread will terminate when it gets a chance or when the flag gets set and the thread get around to seeing it set.

But what about cases where your thread is accessing a server and an HTTP call is currently under way and its blocking until it gets a response. It could be that the timeout is set for a minute, so even if you interrupt the thread or set the flag, it could last a minute before the thread terminates. I don't see any problem with that but some developers might. Not sure what reasons they would have for waiting a lengthy period of time. I do know that you can also terminate the HTTP call immediately, which effectively is what you are doing when you use your browser and terminate the HTTP call when you either decide to hit the browser's stop button or browse to a different page.

Are there any issues I should be aware of when terminating access to a server? In addition, I'm doing this in an Android app. Will that have any special implications?

Comment: A `Thread#interrupt` call should stop your blocking HTTP call, even before the timeout is reached.

Comment: Terminating an HTTP call may not be dangerous but what if there is other code in the thread such as a database operations going on? If an interrupt terminates an HTTP dead in its tracks, I can only assume that it does the same with any database calls, meaning that you could end up with corrupted or indeterminate data in the database. If this is the case, then wouldn't interrupt be a bad choice? It seems that a better choice is to terminate gracefully.

Comment: Any database worth its salt has atomic transactions and safe cleanup for transactions that abort abruptly.

Comment: Are you asking for the kind of issues that can occur from the server-side point of view? In any case, for which technology/library do you want to know the potential issues?